# Restarting a Roo-application flushes its correspondant MySQL-table

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-roo

I've got a Roo-project. Its data is persisted into a MySQL-database (via Hibernate).

When I restart Tomcat the Roo-applications correspondant MySQL-table gets completely flushed. 
All data which is already in the table is deleted.

How can I keep the data?

Comment: Do you mean detaching the entity so changes to it are not written into the database?

Comment: no, I want everything to be written into the database. Lets say I create some objects in the table. Then I add a field to the entity. Now all objects are gone in the database. I want to keep them.

Comment: This is because you have specified `hbm2ddl` property the persistence settings as `create` instead of `update`. See the answer by Constantiner on how to fix it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to play with Hibernate's persistence settings (`{project_root}/src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml`). There is the line:

```
        <!-- value="create" to build a new database on each run; value="update" 
            to modify an existing database; value="create-drop" means the same as "create" 
            but also drops tables when Hibernate closes; value="validate" makes no changes 
            to the database -->
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
```

Set there `validate`.

Comment: Yup, that was it. I will change my question because it is wrong. The database is flushed everytime I start the server because of the property you mention.